# For what is dispose exactly?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dispose

Im trying to figuring out for what I need dispose . Because when im using it im getting an error

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4109 pos 12: '_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
```

So thats why im asking do I needing that for something special ?
im getting this error when im navigating from one page to another and then to another and then back to the first page .
MY error is in a textfield comes from the textfield and im deposing my texeditingcontroller but before calling super in dispose method. But the problem is there that im calling the textediting controller in one page and then use this value in another with setting it as final . And when im disposing the controller in the second page im getting this error . So do I need this ??

This is my code
In this AllFollowersearch im declared it and get set the value to the TextFormField

```
class AllFollowersearch extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/Followersearch';
   final String  receverid;

  const AllFollowersearch({Key key, this.receverid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllFollowersearchState createState() => _AllFollowersearchState();
}

class _AllFollowersearchState extends State<AllFollowersearch> {
  final searchcontroller = new TextEditingController();


  child: TextField(
      controller: searchcontroller,
         decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(
           Icons.search,
            color: Colors.black,
               ),
              border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "search...",
                  ),
                     onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSearching = true;
                                  });
                                }),

  isSearching
                ? Expanded(
                    child: Openallfollower(
                      receiverid: widget.receverid,
                    searchinginput: searchcontroller,
                  ))
```

And in this class im using the value of the TextEditingController controller and dispose this also her

```
class Openallfollower extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController searchinginput;
   static const route = '/allfollower';
   final String receiverid;

  const Openallfollower({Key key, this.receiverid,this.searchinginput}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenallfollowerState createState() => _OpenallfollowerState();
}

@override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant Openallfollower oldWidget) {
    // TODO: implement didUpdateWidget
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you dispose the textEditingController  don't make it final
and in didUpdateWidget re-initialized  tectEditingController to re-used again

Comment: I updated my post you can see a small snippet of my code would you maybe show how to do this im not really sure if im understanding this correctly .

Comment: why you share the same textEditingController between the widget
that you want to do exactly

Comment: What you mean im not really understand what you asking for . Im using the texeditingcontroller for checking the value in openallfollower class . and then showing the user that is typed in. And also add it to addListener method. And this value im getting from the textfield and the textfield is in the class Allfollowersearch